# Javascript json string format replace with regex

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a json in string format. I want to replace keys that start with "name" prefix to to "abc".

for example:

```js
myJson = JSON.stringify([{"nameA": "1", "nameB": 2}])
```

and result should be:

```js
`[{"abc":"1", "abc": 2}]`
```

Comment: The property name "abc" cannot  be repeated in the same object.

Comment: That is a string, it can

Answer (score 2):

Maybe just `(?<=")name[^"]*(?=":)`

```js
myJson.replace(/(?<=")name[^"]*(?=":)/g, "abc")
```

Comment: ok I tried it again it works